# Inequality with number of prime divisors

Tags: inequality

I've got a problem with this inequality. Let $\omega(n)$ be the number of prime divisors of $n$ (as usual, without multiples). Prove that: $2^{\omega(n)} \leq n^{\frac{1}{\log \log n}},$ where $\log n$ is a natural logarithm.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: where did you get this????

Comment: It's wrong for $n = 2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p_n$ denote the $n$-th prime and let $k\#$ be the product of the primes $\leq k$ (called [primorials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial)).  Thus, by definition, $$\omega(p_n\#)=n.$$

Since $n\#>0.92\ e^n$ for $n \geq 563$ (see footnote), if $m \leq 0.92\ e^{n+1}$ and $n \geq 563$, then the greatest primorial not exceeding $m$ is at most $n\#$.  Further, $n\#$ has at least as many prime factors as $m$.  Hence
\begin{align*}
\omega(m) & \leq \omega(n\#) & \text{for } n \geq 563 \text{ and all } m\leq 0.92\ e^{n+1} \leq e^n \\
 & = \omega(p_{\pi(n)}\#) & \text{by definition} \\
 & = \pi(n) \\
\end{align*}
where $\pi$ is the [prime counting function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function).  Thus $$\omega(m) \leq \pi(\log n)$$ for $n \geq e^{563}$ and $m \leq n$.  In particular, $$\omega(n) \leq \pi(\log n).$$

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function) tells us $$\pi(n) \leq \frac{cn}{\log n}$$ for $n \geq 2$, where $c=1.25506$.

We conclude that
\begin{align*}
2^{\omega(n)} & \leq 2^{\pi(\log n)} & \text{for all } n \geq e^{563} \\
& = n^{k\ \pi(\log n)/\log n} & \text{where } k=\log 2 \\
& \leq n^{\frac{ck\log n}{\log n \log\log n}} \\
& < n^{\frac{1}{\log\log n}} & \text{since } ck<1.
\end{align*}

---

Footnote: Will Jagy's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/482646/91818) gives $$\log(x \#) > x \left(1 - \frac{1}{2 \log x} \right)$$ provided $x \geq 563$.  Thus, we can compute that $\log(563 \#) > 0.92\ x$ and by noting that $1 - \frac{1}{2 \log x}$ is an increasing function, this proves that $\log(n \#)>0.92\ n$ for all $n \geq 563$.

Comment: Rebecca, for $n>1,$ we have $$ \log(n \#) < n \left(1 + \frac{1}{2 \log x} \right). $$ This is Theorem 4, formula 3.15 in Rosser and Schoenfeld (1962), Illinois J. Math.

Comment: see http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.ijm/1255631807

Comment: Also, your wikipedia bound with the 1.25506 is true for $x > 1,$ that is Theorem 2, Corollary 1, formula 3.6.

Comment: Thank You, Rebecca! Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks for the comments Will Jagy; I did see them late last night, but needed to sleep.  It's updated now; feels much more complete!

Comment: Good. You would automatically get notified of comments i put underneath one of your answers. Since it is not my answer, it will only call my attention if you type @WillJagy within the comment....Note that the average number of prime divisors is much, much smaller than this maximum, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Kac_theorem