# Is there anything known in general about upper and lower bounds for $\prod_{i\leq n\vee p_n>k}(p_i-k)$

Tags: prime-numbers, products

I have no specific reason to ask this question other than seeing that it comes up quite often when I'm playing around with prime numbers. Let
$$f(n,k)=\prod_{i \leq n\vee p_n>k}(p_i-k)$$
Where $p_i$ is the $i$'th prime.
I was wondering whether there are good lower and upper bounds for this function. From [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450525/is-there-a-better-upper-bound-for-the-primorial-x-than-4x), I know that:
$$f(n,0)<n(1+\dfrac{1}{2\log n})$$
After some testing it looks like $f(n,k)\sim\log p_n\cdot f(n,0)$ But I can't prove anything.

Comment: ... where $p_i$ is the $i$'th prime?

Comment: Yes, it is. I'll add it for clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $m  = \pi(k)$.  Then for $n > m$,
$$\log f(n,k) - \log f(n,0) = \sum_{i=m+1}^n \log(1 - k/p_i) - \sum_{i=1}^m \log(p_i) $$
As $i \to \infty$, $\log(1 - k/p_i) \sim \dfrac{-k}{p_i} \sim \dfrac{-k}{i \log i}$, and $\int_{2}^n 1/(t \log t)\; dt \sim \log \log n$, so we should get
$$ \log f(n,k) - \log f(n,0) \sim -k \log \log n$$
and thus $$\dfrac{f(n,k)}{f(n,0)} = (\log n)^{-k + o(1)}$$
I think that $o(1)$ can be improved to $O(1/\log n)$.

Comment: Does this also mean that for every $k$ there is a constant $C$ such that: $\dfrac{f(n,k)}{f(n,0)}<(\log n)^{-k+C}$?

Comment: Yes, it does...

Comment: Well, then you have answered my question. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh, one more thing. Do you happen to know how one can find the value of such a $C$? I'm specifically trying to find a $C$ fo $k=2$.

Comment: You'd need explicit bounds that reduce it to computations on finitely many $n$.  The [bounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number) $$ \log n + \log \log n - 1 < \dfrac{p_n}{n} < \log n + \log \log n$$
for $n \ge 6$ may help.

Comment: Numerical calculations appear to indicate that $$\dfrac{f(n,2)}{f(n,0)} < (\log n)^{-2}\ \text{for}\ n \ge 3$$ while $$\dfrac{f(2,2)}{f(2,0)} =\frac{ 1}{6} \approx (\log 2)^{-2+6.8866}$$  Of course your inequality doesn't make sense for $n=1$.  And of course $C=2$ works for $n \ge 3$.