# Is this observation equivalent to Legendre's conjecture? $\forall n \in \Bbb N^+, \exists k \in \Bbb N^+:\ \ (n^2)\# \lt k! \lt (n+1)^2\#$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, factorial, conjectures, primorial

Is this observation equivalent to [Legendre's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_conjecture)?

> $$E1:\forall k \in \Bbb N^+ \not \exists n,m \in \Bbb N^+, n \not = m:\ \ \ k! \le n^2\# \lt m^2\# \le (k+1)! $$

This observation is a consequence of some tests regarding the kind answer of @Will Jagy to [a previous question at MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1776794/is-there-an-equivalent-to-the-bertrands-postulate-between-factorials-and-primor).

$E1$ can be also seen as follows:

> $$E2:\forall n \in \Bbb N^+, \exists k \in \Bbb N^+:\ \ (n^2)\# \lt k! \lt (n+1)^2\#$$

Basically, the primorial of a perfect square is always between two factorials $[k,(k+1)!]$, and there not exist another perfect square whose primorial is also inside that same interval. Or in other words: there is at least one factorial between the primorials of two consecutive perfect squares.

I have been able to test up to $100^2$, after that point my computer is quite slow when making the calculation of $(n^2)\#$.

This is the Python code I am using (is not very enhanced, it could be faster, I will try also to make the PARI/GP version). Please use and modify it as you wish:

```
from sympy import factorial, isprime

lop=[] #list of primes
lof=[] #list of factorials

# create the list of primes
nlimit = 10000
for n in range(1,nlimit):
    if isprime(n):
        lop.append(n)
    lof.append(factorial(n))

for n in range(1,101):
    elemcuad = n * n

    # Calculation of the primorial of n^2
    primoelem = 1
    for k in lop:
        if k<elemcuad:
            primoelem = primoelem * k
        else:
            break

    # Calculation of the closest factorial smaller than or equal to the primorial of n^2
    factant = 1
    for t in range(1,nlimit):
        factt = lof[t-1]
        if factt <= primoelem:
            factant = t
        else:
            break

    # Calculation of the closest factorial greater than the primorial of n^2
    factpost=1
    for t in range(factant,factant+30):
        factt = lof[t-1]
        if factt>primoelem:
            factpost = t
            break

    print("[(n),(n+1)^2] = ["+str((n-1)**2)+","+str(elemcuad)+"] : "+str(factant)+"! <= " + str(elemcuad) + "^2# < " +str(factpost)+"!")
```

The output starts as follows:

$1! \le 1 \# \lt 2!$

$3! \le 4 \# \lt 4!$

$5! \le 9 \# \lt 6!$

$7! \le 16 \# \lt 8!$

$11! \le 25 \# \lt 12!$

$14! \le 36 \# \lt 15!$

$19! \le 49 \# \lt 20!$

$...$

Its relationship with the [first Chebyshev function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function) is this expression:

> $$E3: \forall n \in \Bbb N^+, \exists k \in \Bbb N^+, e^{\vartheta (n^2)} \lt k! \lt e^{\vartheta(n+1)^2}$$

or these other ones:

> $$E4: \forall n \in \Bbb N^+, \exists k \in \Bbb N^+, \vartheta (n^2) \lt Ln(k!) \lt \vartheta(n+1)^2$$
>
> $$E5: \forall n \in \Bbb N^+, \exists k \in \Bbb N^+, \vartheta (n^2) \lt \sum_{i\ge1} \sum_{j\ge1} Ln((\frac{k}{i}\#)^{\frac{1}{j}}) \lt \vartheta(n+1)^2$$

Basically because $\vartheta(x)=Ln(x\#)$ and $Ln(k!)=\sum_{i\ge1}\psi(\frac{1}{i}k)=\sum_{i\ge1} \sum_{j\ge1} Ln((\frac{k}{i}\#)^{\frac{1}{j}})$.

I would like to ask the following questions:

> 1. Is it trivial? Are the calculations correct or there is a counterexample? If somebody could kindly test greater intervals would be very appreciated.
> 2. Are $E1,E2,E3,E4,E5$ equivalent to Legendre's conjecture or are they a stronger conjecture?

Comment: What is $x#$?${}$

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD $n\#$ is a notation for the [primorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial).

Comment: @ToTengoUnLCD the product of the primes up to $x$, $x$ included, is one of the primorial definitions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD just in case, relation of primorials and Chebyshev functions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function#Relation_to_primorials

Comment: in your output list, you have numbers like $49^2\#$, which is a primorial of a square of a square. Is this supposed to read $7^2\#$?

Comment: @MarioCarneiro thanks for the feedback... alas! a typo! I will fix it, it is just the perfect square. When I did the Mathjax conversion I did that mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a prime between two squares $n^2,(n+1)^2,$ then the primorial $(n+1)^2\#$ will be greater than $n^2\#$ and otherwise not.

So the existence of a factorial (strictly) between primorials of all consecutive squares implies Legendre's conjecture. That's immediate.

> So E2 implies Legendre's conjecture.

If Legendre's conjecture is true it is hard to see why that would imply E2 and numbers alone are not very persuasive.

Comment: thanks for the answer! the point I wanted to express regarding the observation is that not neccessarily there should be a factorial between the two primorials of both $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$ but heuristically there they are! The question could be: what if neccessarily there must be that factorial there and what would happen if between two primorials of two consecutive perfect squares a factorial is not present.

Comment: @iadvd: By "heuristically" you mean "empirically?" A lot of theorems involving logs don't apply to the short interval so the question seems pretty hard. BTW I upvoted your question, unfortunately someone had put it at -1.

Comment: yes I meant empirically. Thanks again for the feedback!