# Identity of a modification of the primorial function

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, analytic-continuation

The primorial function $n\#$ is defined as the product of all primes less than or equal to $n$.

If $p_i$ is the $i$th prime, I define a function $P(n)$ such that $P(n) = p_n\#$. E.g., $P(1) =2, P(2)=6, P(3) = 30$, and so on. NOTE: this is NOT the primorial function. $4\# = 3\# = 6$, while $P(3) = 30\neq P(2)= 6$. This is not to be confused with $p_4\#= 7\# = 2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7 = 2130$

My questions are:

1. Does $P(n)$ have a known name?
2. Is some kind of analytic continuation known for $P(n)$, a la the Gamma function for factorials? My intuition says such an analytic continuation would require the use of the Riemann Zeta function, but I don’t know

EDIT: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106260/interpolating-the-primorial-p-n) proposed duplicate seemed promising, but it at least appears to be an estimation. It’s possible I did my math wrong here, but:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\log(P(2)) = \log(6) =\sum_{k=1}^2 \log p_n &=& \int_2^3 \log k\;  d\pi(k)\\
\log(k)\pi(k)\biggr|_{2}^{3}-\int_{2}^{3}\frac1k \pi(k)dk.\\
=2\log(3)-\log(2)-\lim_{c->3}\int_{2}^{c}\frac1k \pi(k)dk \\
= 2\log(3)-\log(2)-\lim_{c->3}\int_{2}^{c}\frac1kdk =\log(3) \neq \log(6)
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Comment: No, it doesn’t. The Chebyshev function has the same annoyance as the original primorial for me: for composite number C, C# = P#, where P is the largest prime less than C. I’m looking for a “compressed” form of that function, where $P(x+1) = p_i*P(x)$

Comment: Can you clarify the function you have in mind?  The values you provide just match the usual primorial.   How does yours differ?  What is the first value in which they disagree?

Comment: I edited it up above.

Comment: [here](https://oeis.org/A002110) is the usual primorial function.  As you see, it  never repeats.

Comment: I accidentally deleted the proposed duplicate.  It is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106260/interpolating-the-primorial-p-n?noredirect=1&lq=1)  As you can see, they are speaking of the product of the first $n$ primes, just as you are.

Comment: No, that’s the sequence. And they say in the sequence definition that the $n$th number of the sequence is written $p_n\#$. If the primorial function was what I was looking for, the $n$th number of the sequence would have been written $n$#

Comment: Once again:  Please provide an example of where your function differs from this.  If I define $F(n)$ to be the $n^{th}$ term of that OEIS sequence, is there a value at which $F(n)$ differs from your $P(n)$?

Comment: Edited again. The function definition is a bit misleading

Comment: $F(n) $ is exactly my function. Unfortunately, $F(n)$ equals $p_i\#$, NOT $n\#$

Comment: Ok...but the linked duplicate obviously refers to my $F(n)$.  Hence to your $P(n)$.  Anyway, I'm clearly not seeing what issue you are trying to raise.  Don't think my comments are helping, so I'll stop writing.  Good luck.

Comment: It's "primorial", not "primordial". I edited your title accordingly. Also, avoid the use of `*` to denote multiplication. That a common practice in programming, not in Mathematics.

Comment: Crap. Autocorrect kept fighting me on the function name

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Interpolating the primorial $p_{n}\#$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106260/interpolating-the-primorial-p-n)

Comment: I already linked that question in my own and explained why it doesn’t work.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$P(n) = \prod_{k=1}^n p_k = \prod_{p\le p_n} p$$
so
$$\log P(n) = \sum_{p \le p_n}\log p = \theta(p_n)$$
where $\theta$ is the Chebyshev function.

If you are interested in this function you may use the asymptotic expansions known about $\theta(x)$ and $p_n$.